# Else condition is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner to JavaScript. Can someone help me in this regard?

In the below code the logic for submit button doesn't work. `_btn.addEventListener`. Only the if part is getting executed, some issue with the else part condition. If  the "if" condition gets satisfied then the alert is getting executed and not the conditions in else part even if the date and image is clicked.

```
 <p align=center>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
    </p>


 <script type="text/javascript">
let _img = document.getElementById("img");
let _img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
let _img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
let _picker = document.getElementById("picker");
let _btn = document.getElementById("button");

let isImgClicked = false;
let isDatePicked = false;
/*let ImgClicked = '_img';
let ImgClicked1 = '_img1';
let ImgClicked2 = '_img2';
let DatePicked = '2019';
let DatePicked1 = '2020';*/

_img.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
  ImgClicked=true
});
/*_img1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  ImgClicked1 = true;
});
_img2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  ImgClicked2 = true;
}); */
_picker.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isDatePicked = true;
});
_btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

              if(!isImgClicked || !isDatePicked)
              {
                  alert("select the Year and Click the car image");

              }
              else 
                 {
                  if((isImgClicked == "_img") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked"))
                      {
                      window.location.replace("sample1.html");
                      }
                  else if((isImgClicked == "_img") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked1"))
                      {
                      window.location.replace("sample2.html");
                      }
                  else
                  {
                        if((isImgClicked == "_img1") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked"))
                  {
                  window.location.replace("sample3.html");
                  }
              else if((isImgClicked == "_img1") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked1"))
                  {
                   window.location.replace("sample4.html");
                  }
              else
                      {
                      alert("!!!!");
                      }
                 }
                 }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to reformat this code in the [early return](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) style and to rename `ImgClicked, ImgClickedd, ImgClickeddd` to `ImgClicked, ImgClicked2, ImgClicked3`. Right now, it's really hard for me to see what's happening.

Comment: @Vinitha _picker is defined but it is coming null and hence you cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @Vinitha specify the input field for picker and assign the id=picker, when you click on image and picker field your code will execute else part e.g <input type="text" id="picker"/>

Comment: @VaibhavGidde I have specified id for the picker in div tag.. have pasted  the whole code now

Comment: @Vinitha I am able to see the alert in else part i.e !!!!

Comment: @VaibhavGidde yeah only that is executing..am not sure why the conditions is not getting executed..i tried printing imageclicked1 value in the else part, the value is coming correctly but i dont know why the conditions are not getting executed

Comment: @Vinitha I got your problem you are assigning variable twice please check it and you are comparing with string instead of variable i.e constants you have defined.

Comment: @Vinitha if you look carefully you are comparing true with string and that's why condition is not matched and last else is executing and alerting !!!!

Comment: @VaibhavGidde Thank for the quick help. Am able to understand the logic as you say but am not sure how to modify it exactly since i tried few possibilities. Can you pls help with me that

Answer (score 1):

Here you are assigning isImgClicked = true and ImgClicked = true

```
img.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
  ImgClicked=true
});
```

But you are comparing this boolean with strings. Why?

```
if((isImgClicked == "_img1") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked1"))
```

Fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your function re-written in early-return style:

```
function() {
    if(!isImgClicked || !isDatePicked) {
        alert("select the Year and Click the car image");
        return
    }

    if((isImgClicked == "_img") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked")) {
        window.location.replace("sample1.html");
        return
    }

    if((isImgClicked == "_img") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked1")) {
        window.location.replace("sample2.html");
        return
    }

    if((isImgClicked == "_img1") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked")) {
        window.location.replace("sample3.html");
        return
    }

    if((isImgClicked == "_img1") && (isDatePicked == "DatePicked1")) {
       window.location.replace("sample4.html");
       return
    }

    alert("!!!!");
}
```

Which if statement are you having a problem with?

Comment: only the first if statement is getting executed. if i click both the image and the year it is not getting redirected

Comment: @Vinitha you seem to be initializing the datepicker on `#datepicker` but then listening for clicks on `#picker` - could that be the error?

Comment: @Vinitha try also using `var` instead of `let`, the `let` scope is tricky: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: can we hardcore values inside if condition ?